# Can one use Clarity without Angular?

Tags: angular, vmware-clarity

In recent years I've been mostly using Bootstrap3 for handling css and responsiveness, but a few weeks ago I stumbled on [Clarity Project](https://vmware.github.io/clarity/documentation). The one thing I cannot understand is related to Angular Components that is commonly mentioned in documentation. Example could be found [here](https://vmware.github.io/clarity/documentation/dropdowns#angular-component). The later link mentions HTML-esque tags like `<clr-dropdown>...</clr-dropdown>` or `<clr-icon>...</clr-icon>`. Did I understood it correctly, that usage of such tags only makes sense when using Angular and they will be ignored otherwise?

I have no experience with Angular and I do not intend to learn it, but using these Clarity components in such fashion witjout Angular would be pretty awesome. Have anyone tried it? Does it even makes sense to do so? I haven't found answer in Documentation, so I would be grateful for an answer here.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The home page of the project says: "UX guidelines, HTML/CSS framework, and Angular components working together to craft exceptional experiences". The page you linked to has a gris saying which widgets are angular components. The getting started page says: "These designs are built into our HTML/CSS components, which can be used any web UI, regardless of the underlying JavaScript framework. Clarity also offers a set of well-designed and implemented data-bound components built on top of Angular". Doesn't that answer your question?

Comment: @JB Nizet, stating that they _could work together_ does not mean that they _cannot work separately_. So, no, it doesn't.

Comment: Read the rest of my comment. Read the getting started page.

Comment: @JB Nizet I've seen the UX and UX and UI approaches, I've seen Angular approach. But I don't know whether tags mentioned in the question will work without Angular.

Comment: No, they won't.

Comment: @JB Nizet, thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Clarity has CSS and Angular components. The CSS styling for any component is provided through the `clarity-ui` package, and the `clarity-angular` package has Angular implementations of some of the more complex components. For example, a CSS only datagrid is not possible so the Angular component is the only way to use the datagrid. However, if you wanted to use the datagrid CSS and build your own implementation of the datagrid you are free to do so. The documentation page https://vmware.github.io/clarity/documentation shows the list of components that have an Angular (NG) component.

To have the best Clarity experience today, you would need to use Angular for access to all of the components and implementations, otherwise you'll be on the hook to build the Javascript implementation for the complex behaviors that CSS can't support.

Answer (score 1):

You can, as long as you don't need advanced SPA-like interactions to work *out of the box*. This means, for example dropdowns, modals, date pickers, wizards, ...

Most of the user interaction functionality can be achieved without using Angular, but in most of those cases, it is a real pain to do so. You'll have to work out what's happening in the background and write your own JavaScript handlers to emulate what is normally done by Angular components.

Regarding the user interaction, You'll be definitely able to employ dropdowns, responsive side menus and modals. For the static elements, you can use probably everything you see in the docs. Sometimes though you'll have to dig HTML code generated through Angular-based example.

Note: I've been successfully using Clarity UI for a number of dashboards without Angular with a satisfactory degree of success.

Answer (score -1):

Clarity Project is actually framework free UI/UX guidelines only.

Their documentation seems like they have a highly tight relationship with angular, yet they are not actually. As for your question

```html
<div class="dropdown open">
    <button type="button" class="dropdown-toggle btn btn-link">
        Dropdown Toggle
        <clr-icon shape="caret down"></clr-icon> <!-- Notice here -->
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-menu">
        <h4 class="dropdown-header">Dropdown header</h4>
        <button type="button" class="dropdown-item">Lorem.</button>
        <button type="button" class="dropdown-item">Lorem ipsum.</button>
        <button type="button" class="dropdown-item">Lorem ipsum dolor.</button>
        <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
        <button type="button" class="dropdown-item">Link</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

I took this one from example. As you see the above tree actually doesn't have any angular defined elements except the `<clr-icon>` (which can only be injected to DOM via JavaScript if needed without angular.)

The css styles can be used separately and can be accomplished to build web apps with clarity design guidelines and css without, yet if you need the functionality right now Clarity project is only working with Angular2-5+.

Comment: The first sentence is inaccurate. The rest is kind of unclear. Clarity is not just a UX/UI framework. You can use it that way if you want to, but you'll be copy pasting HTML everywhere, unless you write your own component library on top of it.